# Sorting on Multiple fields mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a query in mongo such that I want to give preference to the first field and then the second field.

Say I have to query such that

```
db.col.find({category: A}).sort({updated: -1, rating: -1}).limit(10).explain()
```

So I created the following index

```
db.col.ensureIndex({category: 1, rating: -1, updated: -1})
```

It worked just fined scanning as many objects as needed, i.e. `10`.

But now I need to query

```
db.col.find({category: { $ne: A}}).sort({updated: -1, rating: -1}).limit(10)
```

So I created the following index:

```
 db.col.ensureIndex({rating: -1, updated: -1})
```

but this leads to scanning of the whole document and when I create

```
 db.col.ensureIndex({ updated: -1 ,rating: -1})
```

It scans less number of documents:

I just want to ask to be clear about sorting on multiple fields and what is the order to be preserved when doing so. By reading the MongoDB documents, it's clear that the field on which we need to perform sorting should be the last field. So that is the case I assumed in my `$ne` query above. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The MongoDB [query optimizer](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Query+Optimizer) works by trying different plans to determine which approach works best for a given query.  The winning plan for that query pattern is then cached for the next ~1,000 queries or until you do an `explain()`.

To understand which query plans were considered, you should use [`explain(1)`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain), eg:

```
db.col.find({category:'A'}).sort({updated: -1}).explain(1)
```

The `allPlans` detail will show all plans that were compared.

If you run a query which is not very selective (for example, if many records match your criteria of `{category: { $ne:'A'}}`), it may be faster for MongoDB to find results using a BasicCursor (table scan) rather than matching against an index.

The order of fields in the *query* generally does not make a difference for the index selection (there are a few exceptions with range queries).  The order of fields in a *sort* does affect the index selection.  If your `sort()` criteria does not match the index order, the result data has to be re-sorted after the index is used (you should see `scanAndOrder:true` in the explain output if this happens).

It's also worth noting that MongoDB will only use [one index per query](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ#IndexingAdviceandFAQ-Oneindexperquery.) (with the exception of `$or`s).

So if you are trying to optimize the query:

```
db.col.find({category:'A'}).sort({updated: -1, rating: -1})
```

You will want to include all three fields in the index:

```
db.col.ensureIndex({category: 1, updated: -1, rating: -1})
```

FYI, if you want to force a particular query to use an index (generally not needed or recommended), there is a [`hint()`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimization#Optimization-Hint) option you can try.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  You still can't ensure you get the sort in the order "rating desc, updated desc" rather that "updated desc, rating desc"

Comment: @jobermark In the original question the query criteria is `category` with a compound sort order of `{updated: -1, rating: -1}`. The order (and direction) of the keys in in the index is important; the suggested index will not efficiently support a search on `content` sorted by `{rating: -1, updated: -1}`. If you are manipulating compound sort values in a driver use an ordered hash/dictionary to ensure ordering is preserved. For more information see [Sort on Multiple Fields](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-on-multiple-fields) in the MongoDB documentation.

Answer (score 1):

That is true but there are two layers of ordering you have here since you are sorting on a compound index.

As you noticed when the first field of the index matches the first field of sort it worked and the index was seen. However when working the other way around it does not.

As such by your own obersvations the order needed to be preserved is query order of fields from first to last. The mongo analyser can sometimes move around fields to match an index but normally it will just try and match the first field, if it cannot it will skip it.

Answer (score 0):

try this code it will sort data first based on name then keeping the 'name' in key holder it will sort 'filter'

```
 var cursor = db.collection('vc').find({   "name" :   { $in: [ /cpu/, /memo/ ]   }     }, { _id: 0, }).sort( { "name":1  ,  "filter": 1 } );
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sort and Index Use

> MongoDB can obtain the results of a sort operation from an index which
> includes the sort fields. MongoDB may use multiple indexes to support
> a sort operation if the sort uses the same indexes as the query
> predicate. ... Sort operations that use an index often have better
> performance than blocking sorts.

```
db.restaurants.find().sort( { "borough": 1, "_id": 1 } )
```

more information :
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/