# find & sort in two orders as in the given priority

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an array in which i want to sort in a particular order like

1. filter for regions
2. find the "weight" `$gte` first and if it does not return results,
3. find the "weight" `$lt` to return the results

The array is always `sorted` based on the `weight` in `ascending` order. 
This is how the array looks like:

```
   "shipping_charges" : [
        {
                "region" : "region3",
                "weight" : 100,
                "rate" : 50
        },
        {
                "region" : "region4",
                "weight" : 100,
                "rate" : 150
        },
        {
                "region" : "region1",
                "weight" : 200,
                "rate" : 20
        },
        {
                "region" : "region1",
                "weight" : 500,
                "rate" : 30
        },
        {
                "region" : "region1",
                "weight" : 1000,
                "rate" : 40
        },
]
```

So far i use the following query ,

```
db.clients.find( { storeID: "asdfasdf" , 
                  "shipping_charges" : { 
                      $elemMatch : { "region" : "region1" ,
                                     "weight" : { $gte : 199 }
                                    } 
                     } 
                 }, { "shipping_charges.$" : 1 } ).pretty();
```

which will give me the first occurrence of the records with weight `$gte 199`. But if i try the same query with `$gte 1050`, i would get nothing as there are no slabs greater than the `weight > 1050`. Since the weight and region are dynamically queried i will have no control but all that i want is the best matching highest slab for a given weight and region.

**What i plan to do ? :** My idea is to run two queries one after the other to first look for anything `$gte` the given weight and if no records, go for the `$lt` (but it will also return me the least one since my array is sorted in weight ascending order so i may have to reorder them before i run the `$lt` query again).

**What i want from this group ? :**

```
 Query1 : 
 region : "region1", weight : 500,

 I want the result as 
        {
                "region" : "region1",
                "weight" : 500,
                "rate" : 30
        },

Query2 :
region : "region1", weight : 1050, 

I want the result as 
        {
                "region" : "region1",
                "weight" : 1000,
                "rate" : 40
        },
Query3:
region : "region1", weight : 50
I want the result as 
        {
                "region" : "region1",
                "weight" : 200,
                "rate" : 20
        },
```

I want to rewrite the query so that it will first look for anything higher than the given weight, if not found, will find the highest of all which should be the closest slab for me. I know this is possible with two separate queries run one after the other depending on the count but is it possible to merge and run it as one single query ?

**Ideal solution ? :** 
Is there a way i can give two `$sort` orders within a single query so that it will first look for `$gte` and then with `$lt` based on which one give results as in the order ? If not, how do i solve this problem either with "find"(preferred) or with aggregate methods ? I prefer doing this in `mongoDB` query itself instead of a `php/js` solution playing around with the complete array,looping etc., but, which is better ? I am open for suggestions.

**Help me with this method**

1. filter the collection { shipping_charges.region : $region },
2. find shipping_charges.weight >= lookup_weight & { shipping_charges.region : $region },  ,
3. only if no records from above, sort descending by shipping_charges.weights
4. find shipping_charges.weight < lookup_weight & { shipping_charges.region : $region }, get the first

This should do i guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting on Multiple fields mongo DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517167/sorting-on-multiple-fields-mongo-db)

Comment: Can you clarify, what would be your expected output from what you posted?

Comment: @user3467349 I just edited my question and given the scenarios & expected results. the link that you gave me talks about sorting on two separate fields. but in my scenario here it is a sort on the same field(weight) but in two different orders(first $gte, second $lt) depending on which one gives me at least 1 result. What kind of index do i need to achieve or have a better performance on my requirement ? Please comment.

Comment: Can you post just the final result you expect, not these numerous queries?

Comment: expected results are given inline the queries for you to go through and understand easily. In a nut shell, all that i want is the closest & highest slab for any given weight.

Comment: You should change your question to focus on getting the nearest match to a specific value - since that seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**update**: This gives the closest match to the `lookup_weight`.

I think as far as I understand the OP, what he is asking for is the closest number to `lookup_weight` (either up or down). (aka is smallest abs difference). Mongodb has a `$near` operator but that only applies to geospatial data.

If you cannot change your data fields - then this method can work (there is no `abs`, so we have to use a `$cond` to reverse our `$subtract` so that we can compare values that are less than to those that are greater then in the same `$sort`.

```
col.aggregate([{"$project": 
{ "difference": 
{"$cond": [ { "$gte": ["$weight", lookup_weight] }, 
{ "$subtract": ["$weight", lookup_weight] }, 
{"$subtract": [lookup_weight, "$weight"] } ] }, 
"weight": "$weight", "rate": "$rate", "region": "$region"} }, 
{"$sort": {"difference": 1}}, 
{"$limit": 1}  ])
```

Comment: I see where you thought you were going here but "i would get nothing as there are no slabs greater than the weight > 1050", was the important quote in the question. Additionally this wouldn't have worked anyway since you did not filter the array content itself with the match condition. But that first statement from the OP is the real reason this approach cannot work.

Comment: I dont think this is what i want. Your aggregate first look for matching $gt 200 to discard rest of the results then go on to sort and grouping. In my scenario(refer query2), it will simply give no results as there are no results matching weight > 1050. What i want is to get the result that is closest for that region which is the weight=1000. I gave the scenarios since i am not just looking only for the highest slab in a region or the lowest but i want the closest ( for 1020grams to be shipped, 1x 1000grams shipping cost would be cheaper than applying 2x500grams slab).

Comment: @Param This is what I told the poster they missed in your question. You really don't want to use aggregate for this and should change the way you record the data. That is what I suggested.

Comment: @Param is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @user3467349 Thanks, i dont think i really understand that query though i guess it is trying to find the difference of the available weight with the given weight, sort them and find the least difference item. this logic looks to be good. where do i put in my "given_weight" integer ? I attempted changing it in the place of lookup_weight but it returns no results.

Comment: just set `lookup_weight =1050` or whatever you need before you query (I'm using `pymongo` not the mongodb cli so the quoting might be different, I haven't used the cli for a while)

Comment: @user3467349 it did not work when i changed all the occurrence of lookup_weight string. please remember this array is in the embedded document so the query needs further editing to work on the embedded document to first match the given region, then scan through each of the rates for that region, find out the difference of the available weight with the given weight, and sort that , pick up the least...

Comment: @Param In that case what you want is a match query for your specific region before you project: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/

Comment: @user3467349 If i use $match, will it filter down the entire array or just the array which has the matching regions ? If it brings down the entire array then i have to carry the $match in every stage in my aggregate. right ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your model is the best for this, but without a clearer explanation of your full intent it's not easy to give other advice. I'll have a crack at explaining what I think is a good approach though.

I could show you a way to brute force this with aggregate, and it's not really simple or ideal. The better idea is to change your schema a little, as in:

```js
        {
                "region" : "region1",
                "minWeight" : 500,
                "maxWeight": 999
                "rate" : 30
        },
        {
                "region" : "region1",
                "minWeight" : 1000,
                "maxWeight": 999999
                "rate" : 40
        }
```

So now there are "minWeight" and "maxWeight" it's easy to query for the range:

```js
db.clients.find(
   { 
      "storeID": "asdfasdf",
      "shipping_charges" : { 
         "$elemMatch": { 
           "region" : "region1" , 
           "minWeight": { "$lte": 1050 },
           "maxWeight": { "$gte": 1050 } 
         }
      }
    }, 
    { "shipping_charges.$" : 1 }
  ).pretty();
```

That's simple, and simple is what you really want because it's fast. Just make sure you use a sensible "maxWeight" on your last entry consistently in every save and filter your query input so that if anything was entered over that number then that set maximum would be used to query instead

---

## Proof Document

Full corrected data with ranges and sorted order:

```js
{

  "storeID": "asdfasdf",
  "shipping_charges" : [
    {
            "region" : "region1",
            "minWeight": 0,
            "maxWeight" : 200,
            "rate" : 20
    },
    {
            "region" : "region1",
            "minWeight" : 201,
            "maxWeight" : 999,
            "rate" : 30
    },
    {
            "region" : "region1",
            "minWeight" : 1000,
            "maxWeight" : 999999,
            "rate" : 40
    },
    {
            "region" : "region3",
            "minWeight": 0,
            "maxWeight" : 999999,
            "rate" : 50
    },
    {
            "region" : "region4",
            "minWeight": 0,
            "maxweight" : 999999,
            "rate" : 150
    }
  ]
}
```

Ensure index which is optimal:

```js
db.store.ensureIndex({ "storeID": 1, "shipping_charges.region": 1 })
```

Cannot use weights here as that would been more than one complex field in the index, which is not allowed. Ideally this data would not be in an array, but separate documents for the most optimal index on all fields required in the query.

And each test case:

**Q1:**

```js
db.store.find(
   { 
      "storeID": "asdfasdf",
      "shipping_charges" : { 
         "$elemMatch": { 
           "region" : "region1" , 
           "minWeight": { "$lte": 500 },
           "maxWeight": { "$gte": 500 } 
         }
      }
    }, 
    { "shipping_charges.$" : 1 }
  ).pretty();
```

Result:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c20f6137ad0dcb15cb8787"),
    "shipping_charges" : [
            {
                    "region" : "region1",
                    "minWeight" : 201,
                    "maxWeight" : 999,
                    "rate" : 30
            }
    ]
}
```

**Q2**:

```js
db.store.find(
   { 
      "storeID": "asdfasdf",
      "shipping_charges" : { 
         "$elemMatch": { 
           "region" : "region1" , 
           "minWeight": { "$lte": 1050 },
           "maxWeight": { "$gte": 1050 } 
         }
      }
    }, 
    { "shipping_charges.$" : 1 }
  ).pretty();
```

Result:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c20f6137ad0dcb15cb8787"),
    "shipping_charges" : [
            {
                    "region" : "region1",
                    "minWeight" : 1000,
                    "maxWeight" : 999999,
                    "rate" : 40
            }
    ]
}
```

**Q3**:

```js
db.store.find(
   { 
      "storeID": "asdfasdf",
      "shipping_charges" : { 
         "$elemMatch": { 
           "region" : "region1" , 
           "minWeight": { "$lte": 50 },
           "maxWeight": { "$gte": 50 } 
         }
      }
    }, 
    { "shipping_charges.$" : 1 }
  ).pretty();
```

Result:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c210f737ad0dcb15cb8788"),
    "shipping_charges" : [
            {
                    "region" : "region1",
                    "minWeight" : 0,
                    "maxWeight" : 200,
                    "rate" : 20
            }
    ]
}
```

Matches only the documents that meet the conditions and without overhead.

Comment: Ah I assumed he wanted equal to or greater then, since you know shipping... I mean he can match by a range with just one weight, there is no need to change the schema for that - but I'm not sure you can get a range that will always match the closest one.

Comment: @user3467349 I don't think you get it. This is not a new problem and the way I have written it here is how It's been solved for years. You want a min and max and the number "always" falls between a range.

Comment: first of all your solution doesn't explicitly do what he asked, second of all there is no reason to change the recording method, since you can always match `"weight": {"$gt": 200, "$lte": 1200} }}`. If he is going to change the recording method he should just change to geospatial and use `$near` since that does exactly what he wants

Comment: @user3467349 I disagree. The point is they know the weight of an item say `210` They don't know the maximum weight range of the rate they want to select or the minimum range as that's data and not the query and the current items are all recorded in separate elements. By telling each cost element that it has a range 0-200, 200-399, 400-500 and so on, then you just supply one number which is the weight of the shipment to select the correct cost. So that is the problem you don't seem to understand. My comment on your code was to point out what does not work and the OP agrees.

Comment: How is your arbitrary range selection better than "$near"? Consider that according to your comment 398 will go to the 200-399, even though it's closer to 450 then to 300....

Comment: @NeilLunn Thats not the way it should be applied. For example, if there are slabs defined as upto 250gms, 500grams, 1000grams, if the customer wants to ship 1050grams, we apply 1000grams slab and the remaining 50 comes from the 250grams slab instead of blinding applying 5x250grams slab or look for something in the range of 1001-1500 range as its not necessarily we will have range defined for any given weight.

Comment: @user3467349 I agree with you. I started to learn about $near to see if that can be applied to my schema even if it requires little tweaking. Any inputs here would help me a lot !!

Comment: @Param Your missing the point. Each "cost" per "region" has a "range" of min/max. A given weight falls within a range. I did already say that I have personally implemented this in large scale applications. That is how it works.

Comment: @Param $near is a geospatial operator. It's not going to help you find out if your "weight" falls within a range. I suggest you actually try what I present in order to see for yourself how it works.

Comment: @NeilLunn You just use points of [weight, 0] and `$near` works perfectly well. He's not asking about weight-range as far as I understand he's asking about nearest value.

Comment: @NeilLunn I agree but every shipping company works in different ways. The challenge here is i wont know all these figures or even what is the range like since min_weight, max_weight, range(difference) are directly defined by the shipping company so i wont know or assume anything here.  Unless i know the range , I wont be able to form the query as you recommended. if i have to do it for one shipping company it may be standard but that's not case here.

Comment: @Param Let's keep it on topic to what I am saying in the post. Your present data has an item you want to resolve to cost and you have a single weight value to query with, that part is understood. But your present data does not allow each item to know what weight that cost item covers but just the "minimum" weight. The next "minimum" is in the following array item. What I am saying is "change your data" to hold both the minimum and maximum weight for the "cost" value you want to resolve to. Then your single "item weight" value will fall between the numbers for one of those items. Understand?

Comment: @Param There is an edit link at the bottom of your question. I would strongly implore you to read through what I have said very carefully and try to understand what I am saying. Questions about that are fine. But unless to tell each discrete item what weight range can be applied to it, then any other way of matching requires "brute force" and is not an efficient search. I'm not trying to solve on the data you presently have, but advising you as to what you should do to make life simple.

Comment: @Param You seem to need a proof of concept here. I have provided one which I suggest you read.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for helping. What i am doing itself is a proof of concept which will be rolled out to my beta product that are being used by several customers. I cannot ask my customers to feed all possible ranges for every region since it is not only cumbersome but also they are lame.What you are saying will work but i dont have a preset figures for the ranges and also the max value. it may differ by 100 or 200 or 500 grams but i cant assume it here. We need a aggr as the other user suggested which is what i am going to try now. Thanks.

Comment: @Param Who is asking your customers do it? It's a logical progression that the next "range" follows the other. Every freight company I know of builds their billing on exactly that principle of between weight ranges. If you are talking about entry through a UI, then make it the only option. In my 24 years of doing this it is the most sensible way to do a lookup. Please see common sense. But if you cannot then fair enough. I've posted enough warnings about poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't achieve it in a single `find()` statement, but you could aggregate it as below. It makes more sense that you do store the `shipping_charges` as an sorted array.

Let:

```
var weight = 50;
var region = "region1";
```

- `Match` all the documents that have at least one `shipping_charges`
  element for the specified `region`.
- `Unwind` the `shipping_charges` field.
- `Match` those un-winded documents which have the same `region` that
  we are looking for.
- `Group` together by `_id`, to get the last `Shipping_charges`
  element, which is also the highest by weight. This element we would
  use, just in case our search weight is greater than all the
  `shipping_weight` element's individual weights.
- `Group` again once more to turn the `largest` element into an `array`
  of a single element. This we do to facilitate the usage of `unwind`
  stage later in the pipeline.
- `Project` a field res as an array of Boolean values stating if we
  have found a matching `shipping_charges` element. If all the elements
  in this array are false, then we have not found a match and we need
  to display the `largest` element as the match.
- `Unwind` the `shipping_charges` elements.
- `Match` those which are of the same region and have an appropriate
  `weight`.
- `Group` those elements together to get the first matching element for
  each document or the `largest` element for each document.

Aggregation Code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match:{"shipping_charges.region":region}},
{$unwind:"$shipping_charges"},
{$match:{"shipping_charges.region":region}},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id",
         "largest":{$last:"$shipping_charges"},
         "shipping_charges":{$push:"$shipping_charges"}}},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id",
         "largest":{$push:"$largest"},
         "shipping_charges":{$first:"$shipping_charges"}}},
{$project:{"largest":1,
           "shipping_charges":1,
           "res":{$map:{
                   "input":"$shipping_charges",
                   "as":"x",
                   "in":{$cond:[{$gte:["$$x.weight",weight]},
                                true,false]}}}}},
{$project:{"largest":1,
           "shipping_charges":1,
           "r":{$anyElementTrue:["$res"]}}},
{$project:{"shipping_charges":{$cond:[{$eq:["$r",true]},
          "$shipping_charges","$largest"]},"r":1}},
{$unwind:"$shipping_charges"},
{$match:{$or:[{"shipping_charges.weight":{$gte:weight}},
              {"r":false}]}},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id",
         "shipping_charges":{$first:"$shipping_charges"}}}
])
```

Though the aggregation involves a number of steps, the initial `match` conditions act as a good filter mechanism to reduce the inflow of documents.

Comment: This is actually presented more complex than it needs to be and I really don't think it's an aggregation contest anyway. It should be about the most efficient way to solve the problem. The most efficient way is to change the schema so that standard queries will work. Whenever I present a complex aggregation statement I try to present that other side of the argument as well, since the latter will be the best performance option always. You can make aggregation produce gold from lead, but it comes at a cost.

Comment: This looks to be more complex. I just edited the question with one more section of my thoughts. Can you help me with the equivalent of aggr to achieive that ?

Comment: @Param - My answer is a solution to the original problem, which i felt could be solved using aggregation and hence posted the aggregation code. You could execute it and see how it fares for large number of records. It becomes tough to answer when you keep editing your question. Am really sorry, but i do not want to deviate from the answer to the original question. So if you would like a solution to a new problem you could post it as a new question and i would happily give my thoughts on that.

Comment: @BatScream Thanks for helping. I am sure your solution looks to be good except it would be a costly solution for me to implement for the requirement that i have in hand. I could not edit the question as i am new here and the option is just not to be found in this page for me. If you could edit my question, please do so. As you said, i will post a new question for the help on the aggr thing that i asked for , if that gives me a solution.