# MongoDB: Use several single indexes or a compound index

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing, database

I am a beginner at MongoDB.
I am using version 3.2.
I read in several places that MongoDB can use only one index in a query, but the pieces of information I found seem a little bit outdated, and I couldn't find something in the official docs.

I have a collection of ~500M products with this form:

```
{_id: ObjectId('574d92332a2b10d7618b4575'), title: A, category_id: ObjectId('574d92332a2b10d7618b4575'), price: 30.23, rating:5 },
{_id: ObjectId('574d92332a2b10d7618b4575'), title: B, category_id: ObjectId('574d92332a2b10d7618b4575'), price: 20.23, rating:3 },
{_id: ObjectId('574d92332a2b10d7618b4575'), title: C, category_id: ObjectId('574d92332a2b10d7618b4575'), price: 10.23, rating:4 }
```

I need to find all products per category, and sort it by rating, then by price, but the final user may also be wanting to just sort it by price directly.

Every single query will need the category_id to be passed, it is compulsery.

I created 3 indexes: `{category_id:1}`, `{rating:1}` and `{price:1}`.

**These queries are fast:**

*Most expensive products per category*
`db.products.find({category_id:ObjectId('574d92332a2b10d7618b4575')}).sort({price:-1})`

*Best products per category*
`db.products.find({category_id:ObjectId('574d92332a2b10d7618b4575')}).sort({rating:-1})`

*Worst products per category*
`db.products.find({category_id:ObjectId('574d92332a2b10d7618b4575')}).sort({rating:1})`

**But this query is incredibly slow**

*Best products per category, then cheapest*
`db.products.find({category_id:ObjectId('574d92332a2b10d7618b4575')}).sort({rating:-1, price:1})`

If you were me, which indexes would you create, and why?
I'm starting to think that having `price` and `rating` alone is stupid, because every query will need the `category_id`, so maybe my indexes should include `category_id`, but [what confuses me is the last paragraph of the official doc about compound indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#sort-order).

I already [read this whole section on the official page of MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) but I can't find an answer to my specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create compound indexes to satisfy your queries, and they should in most cases include your query terms and your sort criteria.

The confusing paragraph that I believe you are referring to is regarding when there are multiple sort criteria, e.g. a compound sort. When you have a compound sort, both the order and the direction of the index entries does matter. If you're only sorting by a single value, the direction of the index (1 or -1, ascending or descending) does not matter.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517167/sorting-on-multiple-fields-mongo-db) for more details and examples. Another good resource is this [Optimizing Compound Indexes](https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/) blog post.

You might want to consider if you really need to allow such a compound sort, for your example it seems more common from most e-commerce sites that you'd only sort by either rating or price but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Use compound index,
**only one index is considered by Mongo at the time of query execution unless there is an OR condition** and use .explain("executionStats")  to see that.

```
db.collection.find({your query}).explain("executionStats")
```

if you execute the above query, you can find the "queryPlanner" object in result which has the detail of winningPlan(index finally considered) and rejectedPlan(all indexes which are initially considered but not good enough as winning one)