# How to sort posts by upvotes AND time in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have a collection of posts where two fields are: upvotes and a timestamp.

I'm trying to add another field called "points" for each post which aggregates the upvotes and timestamp.

i.e. This would allow me to $sort the posts and have the ones with the highest points rise to the top.

For example: if something is posted < 10 minutes ago: 10 points, < 1 hour ago: 6 points, < 4 hours ago: 4 points, 24 hours ago: 0 points. Then 1 upvote is also worth 1 point. two upvotes 2 points etc...

Something posted 4 hours ago (4points) with 3 upvotes (3points) would have 7 points

Something posted 1 hour ago(6points) with 2 upvotes(2points) would have 8 points

Any help much appreciated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting on Multiple fields mongo DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517167/sorting-on-multiple-fields-mongo-db)

Comment: i read that i didn't see how it applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.4 for custom sort.

Use [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) with [`$add`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) to sum the upvotes and weight in  [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to keep the computed value as the extra field in the document followed by [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) sort on field.

[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields-from-output-documents) with exclusion to drop the sort field to get expected output.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$addFields":{
    "sort_order":{
      "$switch":{
        "branches":[
          {"case":{"$lt":[{"$subtract":[new Date(),"$timestamp"]},10*1000],"then":{"$add":["$upvotes",10]}}},
          {"case":{"$lt":[{"$subtract":[new Date(),"$timestamp"]},60*1000],"then":{"$add":["$upvotes",6]}}},
          {"case":{"$lt":[{"$subtract":[new Date(),"$timestamp"]},4*60*1000],"then":{"$add":["$upvotes",4]}}},
          {"case":{"$lt":[{"$subtract":[new Date(),"$timestamp"]},24*60*1000],"then":{"$add":["$upvotes",0]}}}
        ],
        "default":0}
    }
  }},
  {"$sort":{"sort_order":-1}},
  {"$project":{"sort_order":0}}
])
```

Comment: Please provide your comment when you down vote. I can try to address your concerns.

Comment: i didn't downvote, someone else did. 

just reading through now. thanks for providing an answer :)

Comment: this looks great veeram, I've had to look up  loads of the terms. but thanks. 

is there an argument that it is easier to sort the array with javascript after the array returns from mongo?

Comment: Np. it really depends but in your condition it is okay to sort in javascript too instead of server side as it is just bunch of calculations and you dont have much data that you are pulling from server.